# Mellin "Convolution" Theorem

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-transforms, mellin-transform

The Laplace convolution theorem states that
$$\mathcal{L}f\cdot\mathcal{L}g = \mathcal{L}(f*g),$$
where $f*g := \int_0^tf(\tau)g(t-\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau$.

My question is: Is there a function $K$ that satisfies
$$\mathcal{M}f\cdot\mathcal{M}g = \mathcal{M}\left(\int_{0}^{t}K(t,\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau\right)?$$

Comment: Yes, I think it is something like
$$
(f *_{M} g) (t) = \int_0^\infty f(x) g\left(\frac{t}{x}\right) \; \frac{dx}{|x|}
$$
you can replace the additive inverse $-$ with the multiplicative inverse, in the original convolution formula, and convert the additive space $(-\infty,\infty)$ to the multiplicative space $[0,\infty)$, and use the Haar measure $dx/x$ or something along those lines.